# How to reduce pause between two Audio files in python?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to merge both audio files but it seems as if there is a pause of 2 Sec. Can anyone look into it further? It would be a great help.

```
import simpleaudio as sa

filename = '3.wav'
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done() 
filename = '4.wav'
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()`
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that after 3.wav ended, it takes a little time for the program to process the rest of the code. Let the program process both before starting one:

```
import simpleaudio as sa

filename1 = '3.wav'
filename2 = '4.wav'

wave_obj1 = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename1)
wave_obj2 = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename2)

play_obj1 = wave_obj1.play()
play_obj1.wait_done()

play_obj2 = wave_obj2.play()
play_obj2.wait_done()
```